# The real solution for multiple inheritance with different init parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization, multiple-inheritance

This seems like such a simple task, but I've spend way too much time on this now, without a solution. Here's the setup:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, x=0):
    print("A.__init__(x=%d)" % x)

class B(object):
  def __init__(self, y=1):
    print("B.__init__(y=%d)" % y)

class C(A, B):
  def __init__(self, x=2, y=3, z=4):
    super().__init__(x=x, y=y)
    print("C.__init__(z=%d)" % z)
```

That's the idea, but of course this results in

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y'
```

All other attempts have failed in a similar manner, and I could find *no* resource on the internet with the correct solution. The only solutions included replacing all init params with `*args, **kwargs`. This does not really suit my needs.

---

As per request, a real world example:
(This uses a different approach, which has a valid syntax, but produces unwanted results.)

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject

class Settings(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

class SettingsObject(object):
    def __init__(self, settings=None):
        print("Super Init", settings is None)
        self.settings = settings

class MyObject(QObject, SettingsObject):
    def __init__(self, param):
        print("Entering Init")
        QObject.__init__(self)
        SettingsObject.__init__(self, settings=Settings(__file__))
        self.param = param
        print("Leaving Init")
```

Result:

```
Entering Init
Super Init True
Super Init False
Leaving Init
```

I would like the line `Super Init True` to disappear.

Comment: `super` doesn't call *all* superclass methods, just the *next* one. You currently have no way to get `C` correctly set up, as it inherits from classes with incompatible interfaces.

Comment: So there is no way to inherit from two classes with differing init signatures?

Comment: Not unless all of the classes in the hierarchy use `*args` and `**kwargs` correctly so they're at least *compatible*.

Comment: That's pretty disappointing. No workaround?

Comment: What about calling `A.__init__(self, x)` then `B.__init__(self, y)`? That sometimes seems to call one of the methods twice. Once without parameters and once with. What's that all about?

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example? It's not at all clear why this is surprising (or *"disappointing"*). You certainly shouldn't call all of the other methods in the hierarchy yourself, that's what `super` is *for*. I'd recommend reading up on the Liskov substitution principle too.

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to *achieve*, though? Why is `MyObject` both a `QObject` and a `SettingsObject`? It would appear that `QObject` *does* implement inheritance correctly, using `super`; that's why the `SettingsObject.__init__` gets called twice. Also it's not very helpful to show code that *"uses a different approach"* as this changes what the actual question is.

Comment: It is a `QObject` because it uses Signals and slots. It also has Settings, so it is a `SettingsObject`. I dont really get what's not clear.

Comment: What's unclear is **why you're doing that**. What are the settings you want to store on it, and why have you decided to use multiple inheritance to do that? Give some actual context - what's the thing you're really trying to achieve, why did you start doing this in the first place?

Comment: A `SettingsObject` has methods that I use in `MyObject`. `add_setting` for example, which creates an object to `self.settings`.. Also `SettingsObject` cannot have `QObject` as a super class, because it should be usable from an environment where `PyQt5` does not exist. In my real world example there is also a third class, which like `SettingsObject` provides functions as members of `MyObject` which are definitely necessary.

Comment: I really don't get the negativity here. What does `doing inheritance right` even mean, and why am I downvoted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there's a few things you're confused about, so:

1. **Why do you get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y'`**?

   Because the next implementation of `__init__` in the method resolution order (MRO) is `A.__init__`, which only accepts `x`. The MRO is `C` -> `A` -> `B`, so you must make `A.__init__` accept `y` (either specifically or using `**kwargs`) and pass it on (using `super` again) to `B.__init__`.

   `super` doesn't call *every* implementation, and certainly doesn't ensure they all get only the arguments they're expecting, it just calls the *next* implementation with all of the parameters it's given.
2. **Why does `SettingsObject.__init__` get called twice, once with and once without `settings`?**

   It would appear that `QObject.__init__` includes a call to `super().__init__`, which invokes `SettingsObject.__init__` as that's next in `MyObject`'s MRO. However it doesn't pass along any `settings` parameter, so the first time it's invoked you see `settings is None`. The second time you're invoking it directly, and passing `settings` explicitly, so you see `settings is not None`.
3. **How do you write mix-in classes?**

   I think this is the question you should really be asking. `SettingsObject` should be a *mix-in class*, and therefore be designed correctly to collaborate with other classes in the hierarchy it's mixed into. In this case:

   ```
   class SettingsObject:  # (object) isn't needed in 3.x
       def __init__(self, *args, settings=None, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.settings = settings
   ```

   It looks from your example like `QObject.__init__` doesn't have any required parameters, but you should still write the mix-in to play nice in case of optional parameters or reuse elsewhere. Then the `MyObject` implementation looks like:

   ```
   class MyObject(SettingsObject, QObject):

       def __init__(self, param):
           super().__init__(settings=Settings(file))
           self.param = param
   ```

   Note that:

   - mix-in classes appear first when subclassing, so the MRO is `MyObject` -> `SettingsObject` -> `QObject`; and
   - you call `super().__init__`, once, not each of the superclass implementations separately.

---

As an alternative, have you considered **composition**? Perhaps `MyObject` should *take* the settings:

```
 class MyObject(QObject):

     def __init__(self, param, settings=None):
         super().__init__()
         self.param = param
         self.settings = settings

obj = MyObject('something', Settings(__file__))
```

Now you call `self.settings.method(...)` instead of `self.method(...)`, but you don't have the complexity that multiple inheritance introduces.

Comment: I appreciate the effort put into this answer. I had no idea about mixins, and didn't think they were the answer to my problem, but they were of course. I really think it should be easier to find this out, I learned it way too late, and had to basically rewrite all `__init__` methods in my project, totaling about 400 lines of code changed. I still dont get why my question was downvoted though.